# Get names of all files from a folder with Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, directory, filenames

I want to get all file names from a folder using Ruby.

Answer (score 633, accepted):

You also have the shortcut option of

```
Dir["/path/to/search/*"]
```

and if you want to find all Ruby files in any folder or sub-folder:

```
Dir["/path/to/search/**/*.rb"]
```

Comment: Or you can do the same with Dir::glob()

Comment: Also, use `./...` rather than `~/`

Comment: Why is this prefered?

Comment: @MinhTriet what does that do? What is it preferable?

Comment: @marflar - `./` means the current directory, whereas `/` is the root mount point, and `~/` is the user's home directory. If you move the whole project somewhere else, the first one will work, but the other two probably won't.

Comment: Note that Dir["/path/to/search/**/*.*"] will also return folders/sub-folders with a '.' in their name. You need to do an extra check with File.file?(file_or_folder_name) to catch them.

Answer (score 209):

```
Dir.entries(folder)
```

example:

```
Dir.entries(".")
```

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#method-c-entries

Comment: Looks like he's using SO to document the answers to questions he's just asked. A sort of memo, I suppose. Can't see much wrong with that - after all, even though this one is a little incomplete (`Dir#glob` could have perhaps been mentioned, for instance) there's nothing to prevent someone else from posting a Really Good Answer.
'course, I'm mostly a "glass half full" sort of a guy...

Comment: @Mike: In the grand scheme of things, it's probably not a big deal. And as you say if the questions and answers were good, it could be a plus overall for the site. But here both question and answer are so minimal that it doesn't seem especially useful.

Comment: @Telemachus I use `Dir` rarely, and every time I need it I have to read documentation. I have posted my question and answer here so I could find it later, and maybe even help someone with the same question. I think I have heard at SO podcast that there is nothing wrong with such behavior. If you have a better answer, please post it. I have posted what I know, I am not a Ruby ninja. I regularly accept answers with the most votes.

Comment: This can be a better option than `Dir[]` or `Dir.glob` when the argument is a variable.  When `path = '/tmp'`, compare:  `Dir.glob("#{path}/*")` vs `Dir.entries(path)`.  The return values are slightly different (".", ".."), but the latter is easier to grok on a quick glance.

Comment: Dir.entries will return a list that includes "." and "..". If you don't want those, you can use Dir.each_child.

Comment: This is not recursive, e.g. doesn't find `dir/something/else.txt`

Comment: This also returns directories (and not just `.` and `..`).  While directories technically are files, that isn't typically what people mean when they say "files".  There are better answers...

Comment: Self-answers are encouraged, but that doesn't exempt the question from the normal requirements. This thread doesn't pose a question or show any research, just happened to be the first to pick a piece of low-hanging fruit back in 2009.

Answer (score 101):

The following snippets exactly shows the name of the files inside a directory, skipping subdirectories and `"."`, `".."` dotted folders:

```
Dir.entries("your/folder").select { |f| File.file? File.join("your/folder", f) }
```

Comment: Can also do `...select {|f| File.file? f}` for clearer meaning and shorter syntax.

Comment: I'm seeing Dir.entries not give the full path in return filename so this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: @squixy Did you write it out correctly?: `Dir.entries("your/folder").select {|f| File.file? f}`

Comment: Yep. `!File.directory?` is working but `File.file?` not.

Comment: @squixy I had the same problem, in my case I need to provide the full path not just the file name returned by Dir.foreach

Comment: FYI Dir.glob returns full path and filename, Dir.entries does not.  You have to have the full path and filename for either File.file? or File.directory? to work correctly.

Comment: `.reject {|f| File.directory? f}` seems cleaner than `.select{|f| !File.directory? f}`.  Oh, and now I see the first comment... also good.

Comment: The reason File.file? doesn't work is because you're passing a file name instead of the absolute path to that file. File.file?("#{path}/#{file}") should work.

Comment: adding to the list of options ... `.reject!{|file_name| [".","..",".gitignore"].include?(file_name)}`

Answer (score 51):

To get all files (strictly files only) recursively:

```
Dir.glob('path/**/*').select { |e| File.file? e }
```

Or anything that's not a directory (`File.file?` would reject non-regular files):

```
Dir.glob('path/**/*').reject { |e| File.directory? e }
```

## Alternative Solution

Using [`Find#find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html#method-c-find) over a pattern-based lookup method like `Dir.glob` is actually better.  See [this answer to "One-liner to Recursively List Directories in Ruby?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370702/one-liner-to-recursively-list-directories-in-ruby/13569100#13569100).

Answer (score 28):

In Ruby 2.5 you can now use `Dir.children`. It gets filenames as an array except for "." and ".."

Example:

```
Dir.children("testdir")   #=> ["config.h", "main.rb"]
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Dir.html#method-c-children

Answer (score 27):

This works for me:

If you don't want hidden files[1], use **Dir[]**:

```
# With a relative path, Dir[] will return relative paths 
# as `[ './myfile', ... ]`
#
Dir[ './*' ].select{ |f| File.file? f } 

# Want just the filename?
# as: [ 'myfile', ... ]
#
Dir[ '../*' ].select{ |f| File.file? f }.map{ |f| File.basename f }

# Turn them into absolute paths?
# [ '/path/to/myfile', ... ]
#
Dir[ '../*' ].select{ |f| File.file? f }.map{ |f| File.absolute_path f }

# With an absolute path, Dir[] will return absolute paths:
# as: [ '/home/../home/test/myfile', ... ]
#
Dir[ '/home/../home/test/*' ].select{ |f| File.file? f }

# Need the paths to be canonical?
# as: [ '/home/test/myfile', ... ]
#
Dir[ '/home/../home/test/*' ].select{ |f| File.file? f }.map{ |f| File.expand_path f }
```

Now, **Dir.entries** will return hidden files, and you don't need the wildcard asterix (you can just pass the variable with the directory name), but it will return the basename directly, so the File.xxx functions won't work.

```
# In the current working dir:
#
Dir.entries( '.' ).select{ |f| File.file? f }

# In another directory, relative or otherwise, you need to transform the path 
# so it is either absolute, or relative to the current working dir to call File.xxx functions:
#
home = "/home/test"
Dir.entries( home ).select{ |f| File.file? File.join( home, f ) }
```

[1] `.dotfile` on unix, I don't know about Windows

Answer (score 12):

this code returns only filenames with their extension (without a global path)

```
Dir.children("/path/to/folder/")
```

=> [file_1.rb, file_2.html, file_3.js]

Comment: Nice explanation here: https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-2_5-introduces-dir-children-and-dir-each_child

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I found this the most useful for looping over files in a folder, forward looking safety:

```
Dir['/etc/path/*'].each do |file_name|
  next if File.directory? file_name 
end
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a solution to find files in a directory:

```
files = Dir["/work/myfolder/**/*.txt"]

files.each do |file_name|
  if !File.directory? file_name
    puts file_name
    File.open(file_name) do |file|
      file.each_line do |line|
        if line =~ /banco1/
          puts "Found: #{line}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

While getting all the file names in a directory, this snippet can be used to reject both directories [`.`, `..`] and hidden files which start with a `.`

```
files = Dir.entries("your/folder").reject {|f| File.directory?(f) || f[0].include?('.')}
```

Comment: `Dir.entries` returns local file names, not absolute file paths. On the other hand, `File.directory?` expects an absolute file path.  This code does not work as expected.

Comment: It's weird the code doesn't work in your case. As this is a code I have used in a live app which works just fine. I'll recheck my code and post here if there is anything missing from my original working code :)

Comment: @Nathan See my answer for an explanation

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511438/3676469) added in 2013

Answer (score 6):

This is what works for me:

```
Dir.entries(dir).select { |f| File.file?(File.join(dir, f)) }
```

`Dir.entries` returns an array of strings. Then, we have to provide a full path of the file to `File.file?`, unless `dir` is equal to our current working directory. That's why this `File.join()`.

Comment: You need to exclude "." and ".." from entries

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511438/3676469) added in 2013

Answer (score 3):

```
Dir.new('/home/user/foldername').each { |file| puts file }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to use `Rake::FileList` (provided you have `rake` dependency):

```
FileList.new('lib/*').each do |file|
  p file
end
```

According to the API:

> FileLists are lazy. When given a list of glob patterns for possible
> files to be included in the file list, instead of searching the file
> structures to find the files, a FileList holds the pattern for latter
> use.

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Rake/FileList.html

Comment: Filelist is the best solution for large folders, but you have to add .each to your fist line

Answer (score 3):

One simple way could be:

```rb
dir = './' # desired directory
files = Dir.glob(File.join(dir, '**', '*')).select{|file| File.file?(file)}

files.each do |f|
    puts f
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the suggestions in this thread, I wanted to mention that if you need to return dot files as well (.gitignore, etc), with Dir.glob you would need to include a flag as so: 
`Dir.glob("/path/to/dir/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)`
By default, Dir.entries includes dot files, as well as current a parent directories.

For anyone interested, I was curious how the answers here compared to each other in execution time, here was the results against deeply nested hierarchy. The first three results are non-recursive:

```
       user     system      total        real
Dir[*]: (34900 files stepped over 100 iterations)
  0.110729   0.139060   0.249789 (  0.249961)
Dir.glob(*): (34900 files stepped over 100 iterations)
  0.112104   0.142498   0.254602 (  0.254902)
Dir.entries(): (35600 files stepped over 100 iterations)
  0.142441   0.149306   0.291747 (  0.291998)
Dir[**/*]: (2211600 files stepped over 100 iterations)
  9.399860  15.802976  25.202836 ( 25.250166)
Dir.glob(**/*): (2211600 files stepped over 100 iterations)
  9.335318  15.657782  24.993100 ( 25.006243)
Dir.entries() recursive walk: (2705500 files stepped over 100 iterations)
 14.653018  18.602017  33.255035 ( 33.268056)
Dir.glob(**/*, File::FNM_DOTMATCH): (2705500 files stepped over 100 iterations)
 12.178823  19.577409  31.756232 ( 31.767093)
```

These were generated with the following benchmarking script:

```
require 'benchmark'
base_dir = "/path/to/dir/"
n = 100
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("Dir[*]:") do
    i = 0
    n.times do
      i = i + Dir["#{base_dir}*"].select {|f| !File.directory? f}.length
    end
    puts " (#{i} files stepped over #{n} iterations)"
  end
  x.report("Dir.glob(*):") do
    i = 0
    n.times do
      i = i + Dir.glob("#{base_dir}/*").select {|f| !File.directory? f}.length
    end
    puts " (#{i} files stepped over #{n} iterations)"
  end
  x.report("Dir.entries():") do
    i = 0
    n.times do
      i = i + Dir.entries(base_dir).select {|f| !File.directory? File.join(base_dir, f)}.length
    end
    puts " (#{i} files stepped over #{n} iterations)"
  end
  x.report("Dir[**/*]:") do
    i = 0
    n.times do
      i = i + Dir["#{base_dir}**/*"].select {|f| !File.directory? f}.length
    end
    puts " (#{i} files stepped over #{n} iterations)"
  end
  x.report("Dir.glob(**/*):") do
    i = 0
    n.times do
      i = i + Dir.glob("#{base_dir}**/*").select {|f| !File.directory? f}.length
    end
    puts " (#{i} files stepped over #{n} iterations)"
  end
  x.report("Dir.entries() recursive walk:") do
    i = 0
    n.times do
      def walk_dir(dir, result)
        Dir.entries(dir).each do |file|
          next if file == ".." || file == "."

          path = File.join(dir, file)
          if Dir.exist?(path)
            walk_dir(path, result)
          else
            result << file
          end
        end
      end
      result = Array.new
      walk_dir(base_dir, result)
      i = i + result.length
    end
    puts " (#{i} files stepped over #{n} iterations)"
  end
  x.report("Dir.glob(**/*, File::FNM_DOTMATCH):") do
    i = 0
    n.times do
      i = i + Dir.glob("#{base_dir}**/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).select {|f| !File.directory? f}.length
    end
    puts " (#{i} files stepped over #{n} iterations)"
  end
end
```

The differences in file counts are due to `Dir.entries` including hidden files by default. `Dir.entries` ended up taking a bit longer in this case due to needing to rebuild the absolute path of the file to determine if a file was a directory, but even without that it was still taking consistently longer than the other options in the recursive case. This was all using ruby 2.5.1 on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

When loading all names of files in the operating directory you can use

`Dir.glob("*)`

This will return all files within the context that the application is running in (Note for Rails this is the top level directory of the application)

You can do additional matching and recursive searching found here https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_path_content(dir)
  queue = Queue.new
  result = []
  queue << dir
  until queue.empty?
    current = queue.pop
    Dir.entries(current).each { |file|
      full_name = File.join(current, file)
      if not (File.directory? full_name)
        result << full_name
      elsif file != '.' and file != '..'
          queue << full_name
      end
    }
  end
  result
end
```

returns file's relative paths from directory and all subdirectories

Answer (score 1):

If you want get an array of filenames **including symlinks**, use

```
Dir.new('/path/to/dir').entries.reject { |f| File.directory? f }
```

or even

```
Dir.new('/path/to/dir').reject { |f| File.directory? f }
```

and if you want to go **without symlinks**, use

```
Dir.new('/path/to/dir').select { |f| File.file? f }
```

As shown in other answers, use `Dir.glob('/path/to/dir/**/*')` instead of `Dir.new('/path/to/dir')` if you want to get all the files recursively.

Comment: Or just use `*.*`

Answer (score 0):

if you create directories with spaces:

```
mkdir "a b"
touch "a b/c"
```

You don't need to escape the directory names, it will do it automatically:

```
p Dir["a b/*"] # => ["a b/c"]
```