# One-liner to recursively list directories in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, filesystems, recursion

What is the fastest, most optimized, one-liner way to get an array of the directories (excluding files) in Ruby?

How about including files?

Comment: Fastest, most optimized and one-liner can be at odds with readable/maintainable. And, you could find this out using a benchmark and quick testing.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

```
Dir.glob("**/*/") # for directories
Dir.glob("**/*") # for all files
```

Instead of `Dir.glob(foo)` you can also write `Dir[foo]` (however `Dir.glob` can also take a block, in which case it will yield each path instead of creating an array).

[Ruby Glob Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob)

Comment: use `Dir.glob("**/")` unless you also want symlinks

Comment: What about hidden files and directories?

Comment: To include dotfiles in the match results, use the `File::FNM_DOTMATCH` flag.

Comment: Thanks @x-yuri! The flag btw is specified like this: `Dir.glob("**/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)`

Comment: Here's the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob

Comment: An important consideration with `Dir::glob` is that you must escape `\?.[]{}` characters if your paths contain any of those characters.

Answer (score 53):

I believe none of the solutions here deal with hidden directories (e.g. '.test'):

```
require 'find'
Find.find('.') { |e| puts e if File.directory?(e) }
```

Comment: `Find.find('/tmp').collect {|_|_}` Was helpful for me

Comment: Be careful with Find, it doesn't follow symlinks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974087/how-to-make-rubys-find-find-follow-symlinks

Answer (score 36):

For list of directories try

```
Dir['**/']
```

List of files is harder, because in Unix directory is also a file, so you need to test for type or remove entries from returned list which is parent of other entries.

```
Dir['**/*'].reject {|fn| File.directory?(fn) }
```

And for list of all files and directories simply

```
Dir['**/*']
```

Comment: Note that he said "also include files", not "only files" so you don't need to remove the directories.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, I missed this part when I was playing with irb. But I leave this here in case someone might search for something similar :-)

Answer (score 8):

As noted in other answers here, you can use `Dir.glob`. Keep in mind that folders can have lots of strange characters in them, and glob arguments are patterns, so some characters have special meanings. As such, it's unsafe to do something like the following:

```
Dir.glob("#{folder}/**/*")
```

Instead do:

```
Dir.chdir(folder) { Dir.glob("**/*").map {|path| File.expand_path(path) } }
```

Answer (score 7):

## Fast one liner

Only directories

```
`find -type d`.split("\n")
```

Directories and normal files

```
`find -type d -or -type f`.split("\n")`
```

## Pure beautiful ruby

```
require "pathname"

def rec_path(path, file= false)
  puts path
  path.children.collect do |child|
    if file and child.file?
      child
    elsif child.directory?
      rec_path(child, file) + [child]
    end
  end.select { |x| x }.flatten(1)
end

# only directories
rec_path(Pathname.new(dir), false)
# directories and normal files
rec_path(Pathname.new(dir), true)
```

Comment: False:
Dir.glob("#{DIRECTORY}/**/*/").map {|directory| Pathname.new(directory) }

Comment: Can anyone explain the `end.select {}.flatten()` part?  I like the function overall.  It looks like that will create an array of arrays?  Would it be possible to do the `elseif` part with: `rec_path(child, file) << child.to_s` so that you could assign it to an array and get an array of strings?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In PHP or other languages to get the content of a directory and all its subdirectories, you have to write some lines of code, but in Ruby it takes 2 lines:

```
require 'find'
Find.find('./') do |f| p f end
```

this will print the content of the current directory and all its subdirectories.

Or shorter, You can use the `’**’` notation :

```
p Dir['**/*.*']
```

How many lines will you write in PHP or in Java to get the same result?

Comment: Downvoted for directly copy-pasting from http://www.mustap.com/rubyzone_post_162_recursive-directory-listing without citing the source...

Comment: @kivetros I edited the answer to include the archived version of the link :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that combines dynamic discovery of a Rails project directory with Dir.glob:

```
dir = Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'stylesheets', '*'))
```

Comment: I tried this>> `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "*")`, but still couldn't see the sub-folders and files inside the assets folder by `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`

Answer (score -1):

```
Dir.open(Dir.pwd).map { |h| (File.file?(h) ? "#{h} - file" : "#{h} - folder") if h[0] != '.' }
```

dots return nil, use compact

Comment: This is not too elegant, and would need to be on a few more lines to be so

Answer (score -3):

Although not a one line solution, I think this is the best way to do it using ruby calls.

First delete all the files recursively
Second delete all the empty directories

```
Dir.glob("./logs/**/*").each { |file| File.delete(file) if File.file? file }
Dir.glob("./logs/**/*/").each { |directory| Dir.delete(directory) }
```

Comment: He/she doesn't want to delete files/directories.

Comment: How to do this for both files+directory in a single line?

Comment: Wow, this is a really bad answer: a.) it doesn't answer the original question and b.) it is destructive when c&p by an unexperienced ...