# How to make Ruby's Find.find follow symlinks?

Tags: ruby, find, symlink

I have a file hierarchy and some of the sub-directories are relative symlinks. I am using [Ruby's `Find.find`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Find) to crawl through these dirs and find some specific files. However it's not looking into any directory which is a symlink (it follows files which are symlinks).

Looking at the [source code](http://apidock.com/ruby/Find/find) it seems the problem is because it's using `File.lstat(file).directory?` to test if something is a directory. This returns `false` for symlinks but `File.stat.directory?` returns `true`.

How can I make `Find.find` follow symlinks, short of monkey patching it to use `File.stat` instead of `File.lstat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else watching, I ended up using [`Pathname`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Pathname) and the following recursive code:

```
def all_files_under(*paths)
  paths.flatten!
  paths.map! { |p| Pathname.new(p) }
  files = paths.select { |p| p.file? }
  (paths - files).each do |dir|
    files << all_files_under(dir.children)
  end
  files.flatten
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across the similar situation and decided to follow the real path without extra gem.

```
require 'find'

paths = ARGV

search_dirs = paths.dup
found_files = Array.new

until search_dirs.size == 0
  Find.find( search_dirs.shift ) do |path|
    if File.directory?( path ) && File.symlink?( path )
      search_dirs << File.realdirpath( path )
    else
      found_files << path
    end
  end
end

puts found_files.join("\n")
```

This way can't keep the original path with symbolic link but is fine for me at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Use the file-find library by Daniel J. Berger. It's available as a Ruby gem. Then you can find recursively with:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'file/find'
File::Find.new(:follow => false).find { |p| puts p }
```

NB: contrary to the documentation and intuition, setting :follow => false will actually make File::Find follow all symlinks, at least on my machine (Ubuntu 10.04, Ruby 1.8.7, file-find 0.3.4).

There is a bunch of other options available for File::Find, like name pattern, file type, atime, ctime, mtime, etc. Take a look at the RDoc.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using <code>Pathname</code> with a recursive function to do this. I'll try this out next time I'm in that codebase (my question was from Oct'2010).

Answer (score 1):

why not use `Dir` instead ? It follows symlinks
Or you can try [alib](http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/alib/)

To make `Dir` find files recursively, try double asterix `Dir["**/*"]`

Comment: How do I make `Dir` find files recursively? I don't see a method in the Dir class - am I missing something here?

Comment: While "alib" seems to have similar code, I have never heard of it - it's not on github/gemcutter and the name itself (is it really "a lib") doesn't inspire much confidence. Have you used it in production code? How was the experience?

Comment: Dir["**/*"] seems to work only for one level of hierarchy - I had multiple levels, with some of them as symlinks. I ended up using Pathname#children (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Pathname.html#M001721)

Answer (score 1):

Wrote another option with loop checking and only limited recursion. Works with jruby as well.

Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/05c2a976dc16ffee9cac

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler and more efficient version of the recursive Pathname method:

```
def find_files(*paths)
  paths.flatten.map do |path|
    path = Pathname.new(path)
    path.file? ? [path.to_s] : find_files(path.children)
  end.flatten
end
```