# find a file in a nested directory structure

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to find a file by its name within a directory.  I am not sure what the best approach to this problem is.  The file could be nested in other directories within the root directory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2370702/128421. While not an exact duplicate it covers the various ways of scanning a directory. Settle on one of those, and you can craft a solution easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *Dir.glob*, for example:

```
Dir.glob(File.join("**","*.rb"))
```

It will recursively look for "*.rb" files in your current directory.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Dir.glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) or [`Dir[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
Dir['the_directory/**/the_filename']
```

The `**` matches 0 or more directories recursively. It returns an array of filenames that match.

Answer (score 3):

this should work for you:

```
require 'find'

file_name = /log\Z/
path = './'

found_files = Find.find(path).inject([]) do |files, entry|
  File.file?(entry) && File.basename(entry) =~ file_name ?
    files << entry : files
end

p found_files
#=> ["./Maildir/dovecot.index.log", "./pgadmin.log"]
```

change `file_name` and `path` to your needs.

Comment: I am giving lhoffman the accept because his is shorter, but yours works as well

Comment: Shorter shouldn't be the criteria, speed, memory usage and maintainability are more important than size.