# how do I loop through a list of folders and grab a picture file in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need ruby code where i can loop throught a list of folders and then loop through each image individually in that folder

[image: List of folders]

by grabing the pictures file and its name,

I know Dir.foreach is great to get the folder names but how do I get the pictures

Comment: `Dir.glob` will give directories and files.

Comment: I tryed that no luck unless im using it wrong?

Comment: Give example of the code you have used.

Comment: ok :               Dir.foreach("lfw/") do |item|
 
 Dir.glob("lfw/") do |filename|
 Dir.glob("lfw/#{filename}/") do |file|

Comment: this might be a bad example

Comment: ill find a better one ive been writing a lot of these files

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629634/find-a-file-in-a-nested-directory-structure/

Comment: Edit your answer to add the code you have tried.

Comment: upvoted for getting a gold medal before breaking 20 reputation

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a list of each file if it's an image?

If your images are all the same format, IE .jpg, you could use:

```
folder_results = Dir.foreach("your_folder_name") {|x| File.extname(x) }

for file in folder_results
    if (file === '.jpg')
    # do something
    end
end
```

Comment: I put the folder name and I get this error: `open': No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - lfw/ (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: if I set it outside the main folder(the picture ive shown you I get this error: `block in <main>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: its talking about the foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

If you run following code from the base directory of your file structure, then it will list all files ending in ".jpg" or ".png".

```
Dir.glob("./**/*.{jpg,png}").each do |file|
  puts file
end
```