# Ruby function list file recursively

Tags: ruby, file, function

i need a recursive function to list files in a folder:

```
def procdir(dirname)
  data = ''
  Dir.foreach(dirname) do |dir|
    dirpath = dirname + '/' + dir
    if File.directory?(dirpath) then
      if dir != '.' && dir != '..' then
        #puts "DIRECTORY: #{dirpath}" ; 
        procdir(dirpath)
      end
    else
      data += dirpath
    end
  end
  return data
end
```

but the result: is null

Comment: Could you tell me the filesystem? Does `dirname` contains multiple directories itself within it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [One-liner to Recursively List Directories in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370702/one-liner-to-recursively-list-directories-in-ruby)

Answer (score 21):

Stdlib [`Dir#glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) recurses when you give it the `**` glob.

```
def procdir(dir)
  Dir[ File.join(dir, '**', '*') ].reject { |p| File.directory? p }
end
```

Comment: Thank for your responses, i understand my problem.

dbenhur, your code is great!

here is my code if it can help someone

    def procdir(dir)
      Dir[ File.join(dir, '**', '*') ].reject { |p| File.directory? p }
    end
    
    file = procdir('mypath')
    #puts file
    file.each do |filename|
    #puts filename
    test = filename.scan(/SomeRegex/).flatten
    puts test
    (..)
    end

Thank you all

Comment: Nice this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 8):

Use the `find` module:

```
require 'find'

pathes = []
Find.find('.') do |path|
  pathes << path unless FileTest.directory?(path)
end

puts pathes.inspect
```

Answer (score 7):

Old thread but perhaps someone might find it useful:

`array_of_all_files = Dir
  .glob("**/*")
  .reject { |file_path| File.directory? file_path }`

Comment: Why did you repeat an answer nearly identical to the one I [posted eight months earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15503079/1074296)? [`Dir::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) is the same as `Dir.glob`. `File.join('**', '*')` is a more portable way to say `"**/*"`.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know they were identical. And I felt this was more readable (probably, since I used it a bunch of times and never knew another representation of it).

Comment: @dbenhur : Just curious, why would `File.join('**', '*')` be more portable than `"**/*"`. It works on Linux/Windows/MacOs as far as I know.

Comment: @EricDuminil Because there are more operating systems than that.  [`File::join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-join) will join on `File::SEPARATOR` and not assume the underlying OS understands `/`.

Comment: @dbenhur do you have any concrete example where `/` wouldn't work?

Comment: @EricDuminil In the context of `Dir.glob`, slash will always work because the ruby lib is doing the actual globbing.  It's a bad habit to get into though if you want your ruby to be broadly portable. In DOSish systems (Windows), the OS calls usually understand either \ or / but not every program does, so you may construct file paths which will not be understood in that system. Basically, any non-POSIX OS may give you trouble if you assume `File::SEPARATOR == '/'`

Comment: @dbenhur: I agree that it can be a problem when using those paths with other programs. But `File.join` doesn't change anything : `File.join("a","b")` is `"a/b"`, even on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a couple of problems with the recursion:

- The `else` clause appears to associated with the wrong `if`.  It needs to be associated with the first `if`.
- The result of the recursive `procdir` call should be added to `data`.

If you indent the code a little more cleanly, it would probably be easier to spot problems like that.  The following contains the two fixes:

```
def procdir(dirname)
  data = ''
  Dir.foreach(dirname) do |dir|
    dirpath = dirname + '/' + dir
    if File.directory?(dirpath) then
      if dir != '.' && dir != '..' then
        #puts "DIRECTORY: #{dirpath}" ; 
        data += procdir(dirpath)
      end
    else
      data += dirpath
    end
  end
  return data
end
```

Comment: Thank for your responses, i understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file extensions you will have just use this:

`Dir[Rails.root.join('config/locales/**/*.{rb,yml}')]`