# How to recursively change file permissions only in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, file, recursion, permissions

I have been using the function FileUtils.chmod_R to recursively change files and directories permissions under a given path but now want to change only the file permissions and leave the directories as they are.  Looking at the man page for this function I can't see how to do this and I would prefer not to do this with a bash script. Please can someone tell me if this is possible with the FileUtils.chmod_R function or would I have to write additional code to iterate over every file that exist under a given path (recursive) and then FileUtils.chmod it to the desire permission?   I am a ruby newbie so please point me someplace if I am asking anything obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like below - this will change permissions of the list of files matched by `Dir.glob`.

```
FileUtils.chmod 0400, Dir.glob('/path/to/dir/**/*')
```

As mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2370811/794242),

```
Dir.glob("**/*/") # will return list of all directories
Dir.glob("**/*") # will return list of all files
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me.   In the meantime I gone and written a definition  to do this but Dir.glob saves quite a few lines of code!