# Find directory path up in hierarchy recursively on Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to find a directory with name recursively up started from current directory and get it's absolute path. I don't know which directory contains what I need. So I have to check if each upper dir contains what I need.

For example I have such directory tree:

```
.
├── root
├── ...
├── someDir000
│   └── ...
│   └── someDir001
│       ├── otherDir000
│       └── dirPathIWantToFind
│       └── ...
├── someDir002
│   ├── anotherDir000
│   └── anotherDir001
│   ├── myCurrentDir
```

I'm currently in **myCurrentDir** and want to find a path for ** dirPathIWantToFind**, so it should be `/root/someDir000/someDir001/dirPathIWantToFind`.

I know it's possible to go recursively dip down from current dir, but how to do it UP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370702/one-liner-to-recursively-list-directories-in-ruby/13569100

Comment: yes, I saw this answer but it lists only directories DOWN from current. I need to go UP like in bash `cd ..` until reach "dirIWantToFind"

Comment: Is a common root for both files known?

Comment: Yes, it a global root like root in any Unix system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dir.glob(Pathname('/root').join('**/**/dirPathIWantToFind'))
```

See [Dir.glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob). Be warned though - this can take quite a bit of time depending on the size of your file system.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I was wrong in question. I'm sorry. I changed it.

Comment: It might be a deep hierarchy with a lot of dirs inside if starts from root. Is it possible to do it opposite and starts from current directory? In my case it should be much shorter. I'm thinking about to change to upper dir, check if it contains what I need get the path, if not then change upper again.

Comment: You can use `Pathname#ascend` to walk up the directories and then call `Dir.glob(Pathname(current_path).join('**/**/dirPathIWantToFind'))` on each step until you find the directory.