# Read files in directory on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filenames

I am new in ruby on rails and I want to read file names from a specified directory. Can anyone suggest code or any other links?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get names of all files from a folder with Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755665/get-names-of-all-files-from-a-folder-with-ruby)

Comment: Please, don't be selfish and be grateful with the time people waste here to help you and at least accept a valid answer. People will not help you anymore if they see that you are that selfish.

Answer (score 33):

I suggest you use `Dir.entries("target_dir")`

Check the documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000607)

Answer (score 25):

If you want to get all file under particular folder in array:

```
files = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/private/**/*")

#=> ["/home/demo/private/sample_test.ods", "/home/demo/private/sample_test_two.ods", "/home/demo/private/sample_test_three.ods", "/home/demo/private/sample_test_one.ods"]
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to pull up a filtered list of files, you can also use `Dir.glob`:

```
Dir.glob("*.rb")
# => ["application.rb", "environment.rb"]
```

Answer (score 10):

you can basically just get filenames with `File.basename(file)`

```
Dir.glob("path").map{ |s| File.basename(s) }
```

Answer (score 5):

With Ruby on Rails, you should use `Rails.root.join`, it’s cleaner.

`files = Dir.glob(Rails.root.join(‘path’, ‘to’, ‘folder’, '*'))`

Then you get an array with files path.

Answer (score 2):

at first, you have to correctly create the path to your target folder

so example, when your target folder is 'models' in 'app' folder

```
target_folder_path = File.join(Rails.root, "/app/models")
```

and then this returns an array containing all of the filenames

```
Dir.children(target_folder_path)
```

> also this code returns array without “.” and “..”

Answer (score 1):

To list only filenames the most recommendable solution is:

```
irb(main)> Dir.children(Rails.root.join('app', 'models'))
=> ["user.rb", "post.rb", "comment.rb"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for relative paths from your Rails root folder, you can just use `Dir`, such as:

```rb
Dir["app/javascript/content/**/*"]
```

would return, for instance:

```rb
["app/javascript/content/Rails Models.md", "app/javascript/content/Rails Routing.md"]
```