# Get all file names in a directory with ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get names of all files from a folder with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755665/get-names-of-all-files-from-a-folder-with-ruby)

I'm new to `Ruby` and I'm trying to get all the file names from a specific directory. There is only one level, and just need to get the entire list of names. How do I do that? I've looked at some of the other posts on the subject, but none helped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Dir.new('.').each {|file| puts file }
```

Note that this will include . and ..

Answer (score 16):

To list all the entries in the current directory:

```
Dir.entries('.')
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this returns an array of strings that also contains `'.'` and `'..'`.

Answer (score 6):

Seems OP asking about to list only files, not dirs as well.

```
Dir['path/to/dir/*'].select { |e| File.file?(e) }
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use Dir#glob to return specific filenames for specific directory

```
Dir.glob("*") #Get all filenames on current directory
Dir.glob("somedirectory/*") #Get all filenames on some directory
Dir.glob("somedirectory/*.php") #Get specific files with specific extension on some directory
```