# How do I read all the file names of a directory into an array?

Tags: ruby

I want to store all the filenames inside a folder into an array. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: *WHY* do you want to read all the filenames in at once? That isn't a scalable solution since it's possible for a folder to contain many thousands of files.

Comment: These are .conf files created in apache2/sites-enabled. My guess is 3-10 files.

Comment: Why is this not a "real" question? And who cares "why" the OP wants this? Here's an identical question that has been marked as useful >200 times, and its accepted answer (`Dir["/path/to/search/*"]`) is marked as useful >300 times... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755665/get-names-of-all-files-from-a-folder-with-ruby <-- better mark it as **not real** too! muhaha! use your power! put someone down! feel good about yourself! Yeah!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
files = Dir.foreach(dir).select { |x| File.file?("#{dir}/#{x}") }
```

This returns the *filenames*, i.e. *without* folder.

If you need the *complete path*, use something like this:

```
files = Dir.foreach(dir) \
           .map { |x| File.expand_path("#{dir}/#{x}") } \
           .select { |x| File.file?(x) }
```

Comment: i think your code will work. The error is my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kate: As you request, this gives you the filenames inside a folder. If you want the full path, you need to use the second version from my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you, tats great help..

Comment: @Kate: Please see update. My previous versions failed when `dir` was anything other than the current directory.

Comment: Sorry, Yeah no error with this version , Thanks for the extra effort..

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
files = Dir.entries(directory)
```

that returns an array containing all the filenames in the given directory.

Take a look in the [Ruby Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html) for more information.

Comment: It also includes "." and ".."

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `files=Dir.glob(*)`.